# Safely writing directly to a memory address

Tags: c, embedded

I'm writing to a register with a known address.

```
volatile uint32_t *my_address =
    (volatile uint32_t *)MY_ADDRESS;

*my_address = 0x1234;
```

What is the safest way of writing to memory? I've read that it should be put behind a macro and/or I should check that the pointer is not null.

Thanks

Comment: Looks safe enough to me as long as there is no MMU in the way...

Comment: What type of register?

Comment: What you have right there is "non-safely derived pointer". It is implementation-defined if using non-safely derived pointers is allowed in the program. Since my gut feeling is you are writing for some sort of the embedded platform, you should rest assured that all compilers for those platforms allow non-safely derived pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA Never heard this term even though I can guess its meaning.. Any formal reference/definition?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am aware of C++ definition of it: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety I am not actually sure that it is available in C (I didn't really notice the C tag)

Comment: So you don't need to do any kind of null checking?

Comment: NULL checking of what? There is only one pointer and it is explicitly assigned with a non-NULL value (well, I do assume that `MY_ADDRESS` is not `NULL`).

Comment: That's what I mean. How do I know that that part of memory is uninitialized or corrupt for instance?

Comment: It's really not clear what problem you're trying to solve or what you're asking us.  The pointer just points to some memory. No amount of checking of that pointer will tell you if the memory you're pointed to is corrupt, uninitialized, or anything.  It's just a pointer to memory.  What problem are you solving or what problem do you have?

Comment: You can't even safely check is if it's non-zero, as I'm pretty sure there are/were some architectures where that was a readable address...

Comment: Most embedded environments include an SDK or library that provides access to device registers and/or raw memory.  Using those would arguably be the "safest" way since presumably they would incorporate whatever platform dependent idioms are required.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to safely write/read memory-mapped, you could use an already existing piece of code designed for this very purpose, for example ARM's [mmio.h](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/include/lib/mmio.h) header file.

The resulting code equivalent to the one in your example would then be:

```
#include<mmio.h>
// ...
mmio_write_32(MY_ADDRESS, 0x1234);
```

Because the functions included in the header are static inline, there will be no performance penalty caused by a call to a subroutine - the code will just be inserted where it is being called in your program.

Since this header file is being widely used, you can reasonably stop worrying on your register read/write operations by using it.

And because it is licensed under the [BSD 3-Clause](https://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause.html), you are free to use it in both your commercial and pet projects .

Comment: But that is not necessarily *safe* - we don't know if the hardware permits word access there, if the address is aligned or the hardware permits it not to be, and we don't know if anything else like an ISR might see a non-atomic write half-done.  It's also not meaningfully different from the code *in* the question - so what you are really doing is making a deference to authority over something your authority doesn't even claim to provide.

Comment: First of all, I am not making a deference to any authority of any kind. I used the word 'safe' here in the sense that using mmio.h should protect against a misuse of the volatile keyword, I should have elaborated a bit: since  the example code looked more like a beginner's code than the one you would probably have written yourself, I (wrongly?) assumed the question was more a basic one than the one you apparently thought it was - there was no information whatsoever on the actual target. John Smith could probably tell more precisely what he was looking for.

Comment: I 100% do agree with your comment's content, but for the somewhat rude part.

Comment: ...and the ' I've read that it should be put behind a macro' is what guided my answer.